# Conjugacy classes splitting of $S_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that $A_5$ is simple. But how do I tell which even conjugacy classes of $S_5$ split into two conjugacy classes of alternating permutations. When we know that $A_5$ is normal and normal subgroup is a disjoint union of conjugacy classes.

Comment: See the list of *Related* questions in the right margin. In addition to the answers you received here they contain a lot of useful information. I picked the duplicate target largely because it was a highly voted question, and covers all the alternating groups.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Splitting_criterion_for_conjugacy_classes_in_the_alternating_group) under 'In terms of cycle decompositions'

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1480573/if-number-of-conjugates-of-x-in-h-in-g-is-n-then-number-of-conjugates-of/1480654#1480654) Take $G=S_5$ and $H=A_5$. Then, if $\sigma\in A_5$ and $C_{S_5}(\sigma)\leq A_5$ we have $|\mathrm{Conj}_{A_5}(\sigma)|=\frac{1}{2}|\mathrm{Conj}_{S_5}(\sigma)|$, so $\mathrm{Conj}_{S_5}(\sigma)$ splits into two $A_5$-conjugacy classes. If $C_{S_5}(\sigma)\nleq A_5$, then $|\mathrm{Conj}_{S_5}(\sigma)|=|\mathrm{Conj}_{A_5}(\sigma)|$, so $\mathrm{Conj}_{S_5}(\sigma)=\mathrm{Conj}_{A_5}(\sigma)$.

Put another way, the $S_5$-conjugacy class of $\sigma\in A_5$ equals the $A_5$-conjugacy class if, and only if $\sigma$ commutes with an odd permutation. If $\sigma$ does not commute with an odd permutation, then the $S_5$-conjugacy class splits into two $A_5$-conjugacy classes of equal size.

This works for any $n>2$, not just $n=5$.